# sybase Select query in unix

Tags: unix, sybase

- //bin/isql -b -SF2_PR_LV_SL -UAA -bb -DFH2 -w200 -Jroman9 -b
  fre.sh[4]: //bin/isql:  not found.
- SET NOCOUNT ON
  fre.sh[5]: SET:  not found.
- GO
  fre.sh[6]: GO:  not found.
- - date +%Y%m%d
    dat=20180801
- uSE FLASH2
  fre.sh[8]: uSE:  not found.
- GO
  fre.sh[9]: GO:  not found.
- CREATE TABLE
  fre.sh[10]: CREATE:  not found.
  fre.sh[11]: Syntax error at line 12 : `(' is not expected.

someone explain me , How this can be solved?

Comment: You should edit your answer properly, try to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You seem to have pasted SQL code in bash. No wonder it does not execute.

Comment: where is `isql` located on your host?  is `isql` **REALLY** located under `//bin` ? (rhetorical question since the error message is telling us `isql` is **NOT** located under `//bin`); I'd start by finding out where your Sybase software is installed, then source the `SYBASE.sh` file (should be in the top-most Sybase directory), then verify `which isql` can find `isql`; once you find `isql` ... then you need to work on how you submit Sybase/T-SQL code to `isql` (hint: as Adam's pointed out, you're trying to run Sybase/T-SQL code at the UNIX command line ... won't work)

Comment: Thanks Markp, Yes you are correct when I changed the //bin , its works well